# Custom IWordBreaker sample for SQL Server 2008 R2 in any language

Tags: c#, c++, sql-server, delphi, com

Does anyone have a sample of a custom `IWordBreaker` for Sql Server 2008 R2 x64?

I am looking for a sample to start building my own `IWordBreaker`, but so far i have found nothing but the really old `LRSAMPLE` from MSDN which I do not like.

It can be in any language, i do not care. But i prefer it to be in `C++`, `C#` or `Delphi????` (I bet this does not exist!).

Comment: Maybe you can show us what example you already found. Did you mean https://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/0001/01/01/395199.aspx ? I also found http://64.4.10.24/en-us/library/ff819112.aspx#implementing_a_word_beaker and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff819127(v=vs.85).aspx with more information

Comment: @Lars I found all of them also, but none of them shows a working code. They just tell you need to implement some interfaces, but without useful code.

Comment: @RafaelColucci, have you found any code samples on this topic?